# Confirmed Password send to WebApi backend

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

Simple question. Should I send "ConfirmedPassword" in addition to "Password" to my WebApi back end?

I am using ASP.Net Core 2.1preview2 and the Web Api is consumed by Xamarin.Forms clients. I feel I can just confirm that "Password" == "ConfirmedPassword" client side in the UI.

Does anyone know if this has any flaws that I am not considering?

Comment: What is `ConfirmedPassword`?  Like when registering you do a "password" and "confirm password"?  If so, then why would you send "ConfirmedPassword", you _already know_ they are the same.  Just send one

Comment: If you don't have any specific logic using confirmpassword at the server end, you can avoid it.

Comment: You should, yes - you can't rely on the client to validate. What if javascript is disabled?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback also @maccettura yes.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you should send both the password and the confirm password to the server and validate on the server that they match. This is true even if it's a redundant check from what the client is doing. With a public facing web api, all business logic should be confirmed server side. All client validation should be considered a convenience for the user experience.

When designing a web api, I find that it helps to think more generally than just the current client (which is typically a web front end.) What if you write a phone app that uses the same web api? Even Postman can act as a client. For all of the clients, you want to confirm that the passwords they entered match.

I looked at the default AccountController that gets generated for you by the default VS template. It has a Register endpoint that takes a RegisterViewModel, which has BOTH the Password and the ConfirmPassword field. The passwords are compared and an error is thrown if they don't match.

Finally, there is almost no gain in not passing both fields. What's the savings? A single field containing a handful of characters and a string comparison.

Pass the extra value. Always do server side validation. Don't take any shortcuts there, especially with security.

Comment: I disagree. When I finish coding this (my xamarin.forms views) based on the asp.net identity auth views. I will come back and update my opinion. But so far to me it doesn't seem reasonable. It doesn't provide a security benefit. It is only a safe guard for the user.

Comment: To whoever down voted, you may disagree and that's fine. But please don't down vote a well reasoned, well written answer. Provide your own answer if you have a different opinion.